# Retrieve value based on TWO values in a table in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have Table2 (on the left) with 3 columns. I want to use them to automatically define values in Table3 (on the right) based on 2 variables in columns A and B.

I want to automatically insert value in column G based on values in columns E and F, so for example if E3 is "Morrisons" and F3 is "x" then following the master table the value in column G should be "1". So the value in column G is based on two variables: column A and column B.

[image]

I came with this idea, but it doesn't seem to work. Can you please help? Thank you.

```
=INDEX(Table2[V];MATCH(Table3[@[Customer]:[index]];Table2[[A]:[B]];0))
```

also tried this, but didn't work either:

```
=INDEX(Table2[V];MATCH(AND([@Customer];[@index]);AND(Table2[A];Table2[B]);0))
```

Comment: Spill does not work on tables

Comment: Thanks, so if I want to get rid of tables which formula can I use to make sure it allows to check for values in two columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SUMIFS:

```
=SUMIFS(Table2[V],Table2[A],[@Customer],Table2[B],[@Index])
```

[image]

Change the `,` to `;` as needed.